# How do I find the solution of a system of Diophantine equations in two variables?

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

If the first equation is 2x+y=152, and the second is x+2y=100, and it is a fact that both variables are whole numbers and x is larger than y, what is the value of x?

Comment: Use `Solve`: `Solve[{2 x + y == 152, x + 2 y == 100, x > y, {x, y} \[Element] Integers}, {x, y}]`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you were asking for a step-by-step solution.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

WolframAlpha["solve 2 x+y == 152 and x+2 y == 100"]
```

[image]